# How to cast object list into pojo class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Here is the problem I am currently having. My DAO class returns data in index but I want to return the selected data to client in JSON format. How can I do it?

The controller class which returns data in json format.

**MyController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ohlc",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<OhlcResponse> getOhlc(@RequestBody OhlcRequest ohlcRequest) {
    List<OhlcResponse> ohlc = ohlcService.getOhlc(ohlcRequest);
    return ohlc;
}
```

Dao class returns 4 datas (minprice, maxprice, closingprice and previousclosingprice)  by executing stored procedure.

**OhlcDaoImpl.java**

```
public List<OhlcResponse> getOhlc(OhlcRequest ohlcRequest) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("EXEC uspGetOhlc :StockCode, :fromDate, :toDate");
            q.setString("StockCode",ohlcRequest.getStockSymbol());
            q.setDate("fromDate",ohlcRequest.getFromDate());
            q.setDate("toDate", ohlcRequest.getToDate());
    List<OhlcResponse> l = q.list();
    return l;
}
```

**My stored procedure**

```
USE WealthFeedSrv
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetOhlc
@StockCode varchar(50),   
@fromDate date,
@toDate date   
AS
BEGIN

SELECT  spd.ClosingPrice, spd.PreviousClosingPrice, spd.MinPrice, spd.MaxPrice
FROM StockPriceDetl spd
inner join Stock stk on stk.Id = spd.StockId
inner join StockPriceMast spm on spm.Id = spd.MastId
WHERE stk.StockSymbol= @StockCode AND spm.TranDate Between @fromDate and @toDate  
END
GO
```

The pojo class I want returned data to bind.

**OhlcResponse.java**

```
public class OhlcResponse {
private BigDecimal MaxPrice;
private BigDecimal MinPrice;
private BigDecimal PreviousClosingPrice;
private BigDecimal ClosingPrice;

public BigDecimal getMaxPrice() {
    return MaxPrice;
}

public void setMaxPrice(BigDecimal maxPrice) {
    MaxPrice = maxPrice;
}

public BigDecimal getMinPrice() {
    return MinPrice;
}

public void setMinPrice(BigDecimal minPrice) {
    MinPrice = minPrice;
}

public BigDecimal getPreviousClosingPrice() {
    return PreviousClosingPrice;
}

public void setPreviousClosingPrice(BigDecimal previousClosingPrice) {
    PreviousClosingPrice = previousClosingPrice;
}

public BigDecimal getClosingPrice() {
    return ClosingPrice;
}

public void setClosingPrice(BigDecimal closingPrice) {
    ClosingPrice = closingPrice;
}

public OhlcResponse(){

}
}
```

**The result i want**

```
"maxPrice":"200",
"minPrice":"300",
"ClosingPrice":"400",
"PreviousClosingPrice":"500"
```

The error says cannot cast to OhlcResponse. How can I bind the object returned by OhlcDao into OhlcResponse class and return JSON Format?

Comment: What is the `SQLQuery` class that you are using?  Hibernate?  Something else?  Relevant tags are a good idea .....

Comment: it's hibernate.